# Change x value of SVG text from CSS

Tags: html, css, svg

Is there anyway to change the x value of this text from my stylesheet?

< text class="jqx-chart-axis-text" x="7" y="11" width="50" height="37" cursor="default">70000

Answer (score 13):

You can use `transform: translateX(5px)` to change the x coordinate of text element.

Answer (score 2):

You can indirectly affect it, but `x` isn't a css property (yet).

You can e.g affect `text-anchor` with CSS. In the future it should hopefully become possible to style the `transform` in svg content too, but atm it's not supported by all browsers.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. But I need to position this text more precise.

Answer (score 1):

CSS used for **styling** not **changing** value. You need to use Javascript in this case:

```
document.getElementById("jqx-chart-axis-text").setAttribute("x", "10");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5sh6X/

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work.I get the following error: Object #<NodeList> has no method 'setAttribute'.

Comment: the x y coordinates are styling, in my opinion. It's just the same than changing left or top in html, isn't it ?

Comment: @FrankKluytmans: if you get a `NodeList` error you probably didn't use `document.getElementById()`. Here's a fixed up version of the demo above (since that was actually just showing html and not svg): http://jsfiddle.net/pWWA3/

Comment: The problem is that i want to get an element by class name.